# Call to a member function all() on string exception is passing when trying to get $request data

Tags: php, laravel

What I want to do is catch the request data coming from `saveEmployee` function into `$data`. I am sending an array containing `employee` and `skills` from the save function as `$data`.

This is my `ApiConroller`. Line `$data = $request->all()` gives the error.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function pushData($request) {
        $data = $request->all();
        \Log::info($data);
        LogEmployee::dispatch($data);
    }
}
```

This is my `saveEmployee` function in `EmployeeController`:

```php
public function saveEmployee(Request $request) {
    $saveEmployee = Employee::create($request->only(['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'employed_at', 'team_manager_flag', 'team_name']));
    $empId = $saveEmployee->id;
       
    foreach ($request->input('skills') as $id) {
        $empskills = new EmployeeSkills();
        $empskills->employee_id = $empId;
        $empskills->skill_id = $id;
        $empskills->save();            
    }
        
    $data = [
        'employee' => $saveEmployee,
        'skills' => $saveEmployee->skills,
    ];

    $this->apiController->pushData(json_encode($data));

    return back()->with('employee_add', 'Employee added successfuly!');
}
```

I get this error:

> Call to a member function all() on string

Much grateful if anyone can help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **NEVER** instance a controller inside another controller... Redirect if you want to use that logic or extract it in a class (like a `Service class`, not a `Service Provider`) and use it...

So, you are sending `$data` to `ApiController->pushData()` method... but it is a `string` because you are `json_encode`ing it...

Hence, it will never be `$request->all()` valid... it is a `string`...

You will have to refactor that code as you are doing something that should be 100% avoided...

If you want help with that, explain what is the desired behaviour and try something, then show us where are you stuck with the refactor.